# How to get all processes running in .net cf

Tags: compact-framework

I want to get a list of all running application in my windows mobile 6.5 from my application.

Can anyone tell me how to do this for CF??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to P/Invoke the [toolhelp APIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa450775.aspx). There used to be an MSDN article that covered this (it's a bit long to put it all into a post here, though maybe that's a better idea?).  The gist of it can also be found in the [SDF source code over on Github](https://github.com/ctacke/sdf/tree/master/OpenNETCF/OpenNETCF/ToolHelp).

Comment: The link isn't available could you explain the the solution in the answer?

Comment: I hate to keep it a "link answer" but it's really not totally trivial to wrap all of the toolhelp.  Take a look at the updated links - hopefully they'll stay live for a while.

Comment: Thanks! For this week my goal is to make an updater inside a windows mobile application and the compact framework doesn't have a lot of function to work with so toolhelp seems to be everyone go to solution.