# How to determine if a process is running by process name

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, compact-framework

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get all processes running in .net cf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7430982/how-to-get-all-processes-running-in-net-cf)

I have a process called `myprocess.exe`. How can I know if this process is running in my smart device? On the device is installed Windows Mobile 6.1.

Comment: At a guess, you're looking for [`Environment.OSVersion`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.osversion.aspx)

Comment: @millimoose No, it has nothing to do with what I'm asking, but if I'm wrong show me an example.

Comment: Oh, I thought you wanted to detect the current environment somehow. Didn't figure that `myprocess.exe` is some *other* process than the one you're working in.

Comment: Also related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/393881/p-invoking-createtoolhelp32snapshot-failing-in-compact-framework

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7307998/how-to-kill-process-in-windows-ce

Answer (score 0):

I have a google code project called cpumon2 at http://code.google.com/p/win-mobile-code/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fcpumon%2FProcessorUsage%2FCpuMon2

This shows how to build a running process list that can be used to search for a named process and you know then if it is running or not. The code uses reateToolhelp32Snapshot, see http://code.google.com/p/win-mobile-code/source/browse/trunk/cpumon/ProcessorUsage/CpuMon2/Process.cs

I cannot post the code here as it is split into several files (classes)

Answer (score -1):

If you just want to visually verify whether or not your process is running, you can use the Remote Process Viewer that ships as part of VS2008 remote tools. I'm assuming your device is connected via ActiveSync or WMDC.

Comment: I want to verify it in code.